# Liferay portlet sharing objects between portlet class and JSP

Tags: portlet, liferay, sharing

I am new to Portlets and also with Liferay Portal and I want to know how to share a custom object created in the Portlet doView method with the JSP page. I know about adding the object to the ActionRequest and retrieving it in the JSP but is there a better way ?
Thank you guys.

Comment: Do you need your object anywhere else in your portlet other than creating it in doView?

Comment: Do you reach your goal ? I need to do the same also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out Liferay's Inter-portlet communication (IPC).  Here's a link that describes the IPC (via examples) http://wiki.java.net/bin/view/Portlet/JSR168FAQ#How_do_I_achieve_inter_portlet_c

hope this helps.

Comment: The link is down